# grep pattern exacly matching from file and search only in first column

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, regular-expression

I have a bigfile like this:

```
denovo1 xxx yyyy oggugu ddddd
denovo11 ggg hhhh bbbb gggg
denovo22 hhhh yyyy kkkk iiii
denovo2 yyyyy rrrr fffff jjjj
denovo33 hhh yyy eeeee fffff
```

then my pattern file is:

```
denovo1
denovo3
denovo22
```

I'm trying to use `fgrep` in order to extract only the lines exactly matching the pattern in my file (so I want `denovo1` but not `denovo11`). 
I tried to use `-x` for the exact match, but then I got an empty file. 
I tried:

```
fgrep -x --file="pattern" bigfile.txt > clusters.blast.uniq
```

Is there a way to make grep searching only in the first column?

Comment: For first column|word you should add to pattern `^` like `^denovo1` which mean *from start the line*. For search `denovo1` with `denovo11` not included you can modify pattern like `denovo1\b` or `denovo1\>` or add the option `-w` which limits a search by pattern compliant to ***w**hole word*

Comment: Should I add the \b in my pattern file at the end of each line?

Comment: Yes, you can choice any of variants. It is easy to do with `sed --in-place 's/$/\\b/' pattern.file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want the `-w`flag - from `man grep`

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

i.e.

```
grep -wFf patfile file
denovo1 xxx yyyy oggugu ddddd
denovo22 hhhh yyyy kkkk iiii
```

To enforce matching only in the first column, you would need to modify the entries in the pattern file to add a *line anchor*: you could also make use of the `\b` word anchor instead of the command-line `-w` switch e.g. in `patfile`:

```
^denovo1\b
^denovo3\b
^denovo22\b
```

then

```
grep -f patfile file
denovo1 xxx yyyy oggugu ddddd
denovo22 hhhh yyyy kkkk iiii
```

Note that you must drop the `-F` switch if the file contains regular expressions instead of simple fixed strings.

Answer (score 4):

one can use awk too:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0}NR>FNR{if($1==a[$1])print $0}' pattern_file big_file
```

output:

```
denovo1 xxx yyyy oggugu ddddd
denovo22 hhhh yyyy kkkk iiii
```

Comment: +1 that's a nice alternative since it achieves the column restriction without modification to the pattern file