# using grep exact match, using a list file to look into another file

Tags: grep

I have two files - one with some IDs (text file) and other with IDs and descriptions (tab file).

File1:

```
31120
211890
542312
```

File2:

```
chr10 31120 A T Descriptions
Chr11 131120 A T Descriptions
chr12 23765090 G C Descriptions
chr15 784930 A G Descriptions
```

Expected Output:

```
chr10 31120 A T Descriptions
```

Present output:

```
Random selected columns some matching the file1 IDs and some not.
```

I am using `grep -f file1 file2 > output.txt` to match my IDs from `file1` and extract their info from `file2`. However the problem lies, when I have an ID say- 31120. It find me IDs like 31120, 231120, 311200 etc.

Since I am running one file to find patterns in another what can I use to make it specific to my search so that only 31120 is returned. While it is easy to do so in a regular one liner grep search, I don't know how I can do that when 2 files are being compared.

I have tried using `grep -F -f file1 file2` but that did not work.

Now I used grep -Fwf file1 file2, which is not working either.

Comment: can you please post your expected output ?

Comment: Are these IDs always in the 2nd column in file2 ?

Comment: use `-w` option to match only against words...

Comment: This is similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/299476/170373

Comment: @ilkkachu - or [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169402)

Comment: but yeah, `grep -Fwf file1 file2` should work, IF the descriptions don't contain matches for the id's.

Comment: The expected output will be after looking for the ID from file1 and if a match is found, say in case of 31120, the output should be : chr10 31120 A T Descriptions etc. The IDs are always in the 2nd column in File2. However I would need the entire content corresponding to that ID.

Comment: I tried using grep -Fwf file1 file2 on a small test file with 3 IDs in file1 and 7 Descriptive items in file2. It seems to work fine. When I test it in my actual file, which has 18,000 IDs, my output file should contain 18,000 matched entries too. But I am getting 82,000 entries. Any clue why such is the case? Clearly it is picking up non specific matches. I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-w` to match whole words only. As you don't have patterns but fixed string, you may add `-F`.

```
$ grep -wFf file1 file2
chr10 31120 A T Descriptions
```

Another good tool for this job is `join`, but by default it will print the `join` field first and then the remaining fields, which may not be what you like:

```
$ join -2 2 file1 file2
31120 chr10 A T Descriptions
```

`-2 2` means join field for second file is 2.

Beware that for `join`, the inputs need to be sorted lexically on the join field. If they're not sorted already and if your shell supports process substitution (AT&T ksh, zsh, bash), you can do:

```
join -2 -2 <(sort -k1,1 file1) <(sort -k2,2 file2)
```

Comment: How to upvote an edit ? Thanks @Stéphane. Somehow I always forget about the join/sort thing ...

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested grep -Fwf  file1 file2    should work.

If you want to use loops, try

```
for i in `cat file1`; do  grep " "${i}" " file2; done
```

Comment: This 1) uses `$i` unquoted and 2) calls `grep` once for each word in `file1` which will be extremely slow (as it needs to read the entire `file2` every time).